# Idiom for exception safety relating to constructor parameters

Tags: c++, exception-safety

I've been looking at some code I'm working on, and we have the equivalent of this:

```
AutoPtr<A> x;
...
/// x gets initialized
...
B* y = new B(x.Detach());
```

Where AutoPtr is our version of auto_ptr, and Detach() returns the owned pointer and resets itself. Also, B() takes ownership of x.

Now, I realized that this will leak x if new throws an std::bad_alloc, so I changed the code to this:

```
AutoPtr<A> x;
...
/// x gets initialized
...
B* y = new B(x.Get());
x.Detach();
```

But then I realized that if B() 'owns' the pointer, and an exception happens during its construction, it should take care of deleting the parameter itself (or should it?), so the x will get deleted twice, once by B(), and once by x's destructor.

Now, is there a C++ idiom that gets around this problem, for example, making code that calls constructors responsible for cleaning up parameters? Most code I've seen doesn't seem to do that...

Comment: I assume the `B*` is actually `AutoPtr<B>`?

Comment: hah, no it isn't, as it gets passed into another function that takes ownership of it on the next line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious solution seems to be to pass a temporary `AutoPtr<A>` to the constructor of `B`:

```
AutoPtr<B> y(new B(AutoPtr<A>(x));
```

(this also adds resource control for the `B*` returned from `new B()`).

`B`'s constructor would just call `x.Detach()` to initialize whatever it needs to initialize with the `A*`. If an exception occurs at any point, the `AutoPtr<A>` will release the object.

If you want to retain the `A` object managed by `x` in case of an exception, you can pass a `AutoPtr<A>&` to the constructor of `B` instead.

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning for passing a copy of the `AutoPtr<A>` rather than by reference.

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense. Unfortunately this code has constructors accepting raw owning pointers everywhere, so I doubt this is going to be implemented, as the probability of a bad_alloc isn't really worth the effort.

Comment: @Bwmat: At least _add_ this constructor, and begin to use it.  Better safe sometimes than safe never.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The best choice would be to add two constructors: one taking the `AutoPtr<A>` by reference and the other one by value. For the minimal change, i.e., just add one constructor, I would opt for the one taking the `AutoPtr<A>` by value because this avoids the need to name a variable when there is only a temporary, e.g., when the pointer is returned from a function. Since copying an `std::auto_ptr<T>` and presumable also an `AutoPtr<T>` is cheap it comes down to whether the object is typically named or not which is easier to use.

Answer (score 3):

> ...it should take care of deleting the parameter itself (or should it?)

No, it should not.

`B` doesn't exist until the constructor completes, and if it doesn't exist it shouldn't claim ownership of anything (to a point; if the constructor itself did something, that needs to be safe as well).

The C++ idiom is to not use raw pointers for ownership (including for `y`)! `B` should accept the `AutoPtr` as an argument so the caller can give up ownership this way. This is the goal of `std::unique_ptr` and `std::move`:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> x;

std::unique_ptr<B> y(new B(std::move(x)));
```

Also note that really `new` should not be used like this as well; instead use the `make_*` utilities:

```
auto y = std::make_unique<B>(std::move(x));
```

But this is missing currently as oversight.

Comment: I really wish we could use std::unique_ptr, but C+11 isn't happening over here for a _while_

Comment: @Bwmat: `auto_ptr` works for this purpose.  Your `AutoPtr` ought to as well.

Comment: I was thinking about move semantics, actually. I guess they're not really neccessary though.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, may be:

```
B* y = new B();
y->Attach(x.Detach());
```

or

```
B* y = new B();
(*y) = x;
```

Comment: Two phase initialization is bad

Comment: @MooingDuck dynamic allocation of `AutoPtr` is bad, actually

Comment: Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see that anyone, including the OP, has suggested or implied that dynamic allocation of an `AutoPtr` would be good.